# Hide header inside DrawerNavigator (react-navigation)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Hye..

I currently playing around react-navigation and trying to solve issue where header did not hide when Drawer open...

[image]

I hope anyone can share how to solve this buggy header..below I attached my code integration of DrawerNavigator inside StackNavigator.

```js
const Home = DrawerNavigator({
  HomeMenu: { screen: HomeMenu },
  Messages: { screen: Messages },
  Notifications: { screen: Notifications },
  Badges: { screen: Badges },
  Leaderboard: { screen: Leaderboard },
  Profile: { screen: Profile },
  Logout: { screen: Logout }
});

const MainActivity = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home }
})
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You can hide header like:-

```
const Home = DrawerNavigator({
  HomeMenu: { screen: HomeMenu,
    navigationOptions: {
          header:false, //hide header if not needed so whole screen slide  

    },
},
  Messages: { screen: Messages },
  Notifications: { screen: Notifications },
  Badges: { screen: Badges },
  Leaderboard: { screen: Leaderboard },
  Profile: { screen: Profile },
  Logout: { screen: Logout }
});

const MainActivity = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home }
})
```

Comment: Replacing `header:false` with `drawerLabel: () => null` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use **StackNavigator** inside **DrawerNavigator** and set `headerMode: 'none'` to root StackNavigator

```
const MenuStackNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Dashboard: { 
    screen: Dashboard, 
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Dashboard',
    }
  },
});
const PagesStackNavigator = StackNavigator({...});

const DrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
  MenuStack: { 
    screen: MenuStackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawer: () => ({
        label: 'MenuStackNavigator',
      })
    },
  },
  Pages: { 
    screen: PagesStackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawer: () => ({
        label: 'PagesStackNavigator',
      })
    },
  }
});

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Drawer: { screen: DrawerNavigator },
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue (TabNav nested inside DrawerNav) and found a *super* easy fix I wanted to share! This issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/795), in the repo for `react-navigation`. The fix that I implemented (on the screen you want to hide):

```
MAIN: {
  screen: MainTabs,
  navigationOptions: {
    drawerLabel: () => null // to hide this header
},
```

},

Slightly different version:

```
static navigationOptions = {
drawerLabel: () => null
```

}

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found the ways, I just need to do the other way around..
Make DrawerNavigator as the root Navigator and put StackNavigator inside it.. then there will be no header when open the drawer

Answer (score 0):

I was also playing around this problem and found out that StackNavigator has to be nested inside Drawer one, but there are a lot of issues about this solution like synchronizing active menu state inside drawer and card stack.

```
// Manifest of possible screens

const MenuButton = ({ navigation }) => (
    <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}>
            <Icon name="bars" style={{color: 'white', padding: 10, marginLeft:10, fontSize: 20}}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
);

const Nav = StackNavigator({
  StoriesScreen: {
    screen: StoriesScreen,
    navigationOptions: { title: 'Stories' }
  },
  LaunchScreen: { screen: LaunchScreen },
  LoginScreen: {
    screen: LoginScreen,
    navigationOptions: { title: 'Login' }
  }
}, {
  navigationOptions: {
    header: navigation => ({
      style: styles.header,
      left: <MenuButton navigation={navigation} />,
    }),
  }
})

const PrimaryNav = DrawerNavigator({
  StoriesScreen: {
    screen: Nav,
    navigationOptions: { title: 'Stories' }
  },
  LaunchScreen: { screen: LaunchScreen },
  LoginScreen: {
    screen: LoginScreen,
    navigationOptions: { title: 'Login' }
  }
})
```

Comment: I see... I never check the others things related when nested stack inside drawerNavigator.. thanks for heads up!

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue and solved by add "headerMode":none in main StackNavigator.

Example:

```
const AppMainStack = DrawerNavigator({
  ActivitiesScreen: {screen: ActivitiesScreen},
}, {
  drawerPosition: 'right',
});

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  StartScreen: {screen: StartScreen},
  EnterCodeScreen: {screen: EnterCodeScreen},
  CreateAccountScreen: {screen: CreateAccountScreen},
  ProfileSetupScreen: {screen: ProfileSetupScreen},
  SignInScreen: {screen: AppMainStack},
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use screenOptions and set a "null" header function like that:

```
    <Drawer.Navigator
        screenOptions={{ header: () => <View /> }}
        initialRouteName="HomeStack"
    >
        <Drawer.Screen name="HomeStack" component={HomeStack} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
```